# Python Django jquery

Tags: python, django, filter

Before in my models.py I had

```
report_division = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=40)
```

and I counted by filter using this line in my views.py:

```
CRS = Post.objects.filter(report_division='Something').count()
```

Now I have a seperate class in my models.py

```
class Divizija(models.Model):
    naziv_divizija = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.naziv_divizija

class Post(models.Model):
     report_division = models.ForeignKey(Divizija, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, 
     verbose_name="Divizija")
```

I can't get my query to work now. I tried:

```
CRS = Post.objects.filter(report_division=1).count()
CRS = Post.objects.filter(report_division_id=1).count()
CRS = Post.objects.filter(report_division='Something').count()
```

Comment: second one should work `Post.objects.filter(report_division_id=1).count()` what do you mean by not working is it giving you an error or is it not giving you the correct count?

Comment: It's working, donno why I didn't at start, maybe my mistake. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the field of the foreign key you want to filter by

```
CRS = Post.objects.filter(report_division__naziv_divizija=1).count()
CRS = Post.objects.filter(report_division_id=1).count()  # this one is right
CRS = Post.objects.filter(report_division__naziv_divizija='Something').count()
```